# Unable to Debug xUnit tests in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xunit

I've recently switched from `Visual Studio 2012` to `2015`, and I can no longer use the `debug` functionality for my `xUnit` tests.

I see my tests in the `Test Explorer` window, I can execute them with `Run Selected Tests` but when I click the `Debug Selected Tests`, the Output windows pops up with the following:

```
------ Run test started ------
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:02,1964623) ==========
```

But nothing happens....

I've tried `Debug` and `Release` Modes within `Visual Studio`, I've changed the `Debug > Options... > Use Managed / Native Compatibility Mode` as suggested on some forums, but nothing seems to work :S

I have the following `NuGet packages`:

```
<packages>
  <package id="xunit" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="xunit.assert" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="xunit.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Has anyone encountered such a behavior? Is there a magical setting I've missed?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting TestClass.cs not found?  I am unable to debug as well.  I can run, but I cannot debug.  You need to find TestClass.cs to test.  but i have no testclass.cs that I can find.

Comment: I somehow manage to make it work by playing with x86 architecture settings in the Unit Test Sessions window. I have, since then, moved on to a new machine so I cannot help you :S